# Atmospheric correction for planet images using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, atmospheric-correction, planet

I am very much new to the field of image processing. I have several images from planetscope. *20190722_155754_1049_3B_AnalyticMS* is one of them. I don't know how to process these images in ArcGIS Desktop.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Are you interested specifically in atmospherically correcting the Planet imagery? Are you interested in surface reflectance?

Comment: I want to extract the surface reflectance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform image processing in the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture I think you should start by reviewing the [Image Analysis window: Processing section](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/image-analysis-window-processing-section.htm) in the Online Help:

> The Image Analysis window's Processing section simplifies the
> experience of applying complex processing and analysis techniques to
> layers of image and raster data in ArcMap. The tools provide one-click
> options to apply processes, such as clipping, normalized difference
> vegetation index (NDVI) creation, mosaicking, and exporting. The tools
> are responsive to the selected layers in the window and are activated
> only when the appropriate inputs for the processes are selected. More
> than one layer can be chosen, and using the tool applies the
> processing or analysis to each layer creating temporary layers in the
> table of contents.

I am not certain that the Image Analysis window was present in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0, but it appears to have been available since at least ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.